# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

Tags: asp-classic

I uploaded my project on web hosting, and when I request my page it give me this error:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'
>
> 'C:\webng.com\wwwroot\data\guestbook.mdb' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.
>
> /_____10_/weeklyfreerare/add_to_guestbook.asp, line 60

My code:

```
adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("/data/guestbook.mdb") & ";"
```

Comment: Where is your mdb file stored ? Try `Server.MapPath("data/guestbook.mdb")` without the `/` at the beginning.

Comment: in my web host on "data" folder

Comment: @user3779883 did you try what was suggested in the comment? `Server.MapPath("data/guestbook.mdb")` should indeed do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Usually most web hosts data folder is located outside of the wwwroot folder.

I have a function called DataPath that I use to get this folder. You can use this function and change your Open command like this:

```
adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DataPath() & "\guestbook.mdb" & ";"

Function DataPath()
    Dim strPath, intPos

    strPath = Server.MapPath("/")
    intPos = InStrRev(strPath, "\")
    strPath = Left(strPath, intPos)

    DataPath = strPath + "\data"
End Function
```